# Unescape JavaScript's escape() using C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Are the any functions in C# that handle escape/unescape like JavaScript?

I have a JSON string like this:

`{"Feeds":[{"Url":"www.test.com","FeedType":"Twitter"},{"Url":"www.test2.com","FeedType":"Youtube"}]}`

Which looks like this after `escape()`

`%7B%22Feeds%22%3A%5B%7B%22Url%22%3A%22www.test.com%22%2C%22FeedType%22%3A%22Twitter%22%7D%2C%7B%22Url%22%3A%22www.test2.com%22%2C%22FeedType%22%3A%22Youtube%22%7D%5D%7D`

In my C# code I would like to unescape this string so that it looks exactly the same as it did before the `escape()`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

[`HttpUtility.UrlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy.aspx) should do the trick.

Comment: @Timwi - You are correct. I mis-read. Updated. Just out of curiosity, why did you roll your own code (now deleted) to do the same thing instead of re-using what .NET provides?

Comment: Thx, I tried `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` but it did not work, but when I see your answer I see that `UrlDecode` does something that `HtmlDecode` did not do.

Comment: @Martin - Yeah. `HtmlDecode` is for decoding escaped HTML characters. URL Encoding involves more rules.

Comment: Well firstly because I didn’t know about it at the time. Secondly because `HttpUtility` requires a reference to `System.Web.dll`, which is filled to the rim with stuff I have no use for. But thirdly because I enjoy rolling my own... I rolled my own webserver too... :-p

Comment: This doesn't handle the '+' char. (Try using UrlDecode on "abc+def" it seems to be replacing the + with a space.) Temporarily I am using Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.unencode() But I hate bringing in a dependency just for that...

Comment: "+" is a space character in a URL.  It's up to the encoder to escape that as well.   In JavaScript you want to use encodeURIComponent instead of escape, which also covers the + character.

Comment: This is not decoding swedish characters properly- å gets escaped to %E5 and decoded to: �

Comment: Downvoted, the second answer worked for "Lucía", this one didn't

Answer (score 22):

`escape()` is equivalent to

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(str, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
```

---

By default the `UrlDecode` uses UTF8 while `escape()` don't.

Comment: UTF8 is backward compatible with ASCII so, unless I'm mis-understanding something, you shouldn't have to pass in the encoding.

Comment: This is wrong... escape() is actually equivalent to `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(str, Encoding.Default)`, which means two things: ① it depends on your system locale settings; and ② it is obsolete 1990s 8-bit technology and incompatible with UTF-8. (The second paragraph is correct though.)

Comment: @Justin Niessner: As you said, it is backward `compatible`. Not equivalent. And I want to give emphasis on `backward`, don't even think it's compatible the other way.

Comment: HttpUtility.UrlDecode(msg, System.Text.Encoding.Default); 

Works for me actually

Comment: for languages with special chars this did the trick, thank you sir

Answer (score 11):

This is the best way I found to work with these:

Encode in C#:

```
System.Uri.EscapeDataString("<string>");
```

Decode in JavaScript:

```
decodeURI("<string>");
```

Encode in JavaScript:

```
encodeURI("<string>");
```

Decode in C#:

```
System.Uri.UnescapeDataString("<string>");
```

**Update 27-Jan-2016**: Just found what seems do be a more compatible way to do it, which also encodes the URI protocol (http://) using javascript:

Encode in JavaScript:

```
encodeURIComponent("<string>");
```

Decode in JavaScript:

```
decodeURIComponent("<string>");
```

Answer (score 5):

Aw man, why do we over-think stuff so much sometimes.
When an API function is being silly, send a karma cuss at the library developer, then work-around it...

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(editext, System.Text.Encoding.Default).Replace("+","%20");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    internal static string UnJavascriptEscape(string s)
    {
        // undo the effects of JavaScript's escape function
        return HttpUtility.UrlDecode(s.Replace("+", "%2b"), Encoding.Default);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To unescape without having to reference System.Web in order to use HttpUtility, try this:

```
Str = Str.Replace("+", " ");
Str = Regex.Replace(Str, "%([A-Fa-f\\d]{2})", a => "" + Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(a.Groups[1].Value, 16)));
```

Also, when I tried HttpUtility.UrlDecode, it didn't work for special characters áéíóúñ.

Answer (score 0):

I spent 8 hours trying to get

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode
```

to work, and gave up and used

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode
```

which worked instantly.