# How to decode a string encoded with JavaScriptStringEncoded?

Tags: c#, javascript, json, encoding

Is there a method to decode a string encoded with HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode() in C#?

Example encoded string:

```
<div class=\"header\"><h2>\u00FC<\/h2><script>\n<\/script>\n
```

My temporary solution is:

```
public static string JavaScriptStringDecode(string source)
{
    // Replace some chars.
    var decoded = source.Replace(@"\'", "'")
                .Replace(@"\""", @"""")
                .Replace(@"\/", "/")
                .Replace(@"\t", "\t")
                .Replace(@"\n", "\n");

    // Replace unicode escaped text.
    var rx = new Regex(@"\\[uU]([0-9A-F]{4})");

    decoded = rx.Replace(decoded, match => ((char)Int32.Parse(match.Value.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber))
                                            .ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

    return decoded;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode(v=vs.110).aspx

also answered here: [Unescape JavaScript's escape() using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778165/unescape-javascripts-escape-using-c-sharp)

But, UrlDecode has some significant limitations around certain characters (like + signs, which javascript doesn't unescape) and any character values >= 128. Using Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.unescape is probably the most reliable, but I don't know how well it performs (i.e. what the backing language is. I'd imagine it's fast given it's a lib at this point).

Answer (score 0):

No, you would have to implement that yourself. The reason is that there is just no intented usage for such a method! For what you are probably trying to achieve, why not just use

```
HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode(...)
```

and

```
HttpServerUtility.HtmlDecode(...)
```

Comment: Intended use is web content parser. I don't own the content.

Answer (score 0):

I use HttpUtility.UrlEncode instead of HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode, and then
HttpUtility.UrlDecode.

Answer (score 0):

System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(string json)
will do it for you except the case when original string was null - it returns "" instead.Do not forget to put encoded string inside double quotes before. HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(str,true) overload will do it automatically.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).